# Difference between the pronunciations of "The"

Tags: definite-article, pronunciation

I have heard normally people speaking *the* in two different ways.

> First *the,*  *th-uh* 
>   Second *the,* *thee*

I think there is something with vowel sound.  Is there is really a difference or just accent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the dialect whether this difference occurs.

> Th-uh

This would be before words starting with consontants (the book = "thuh buk")

> Thee

This is before vowels (the apple = "thee apple")

Comment: Nah, I'd say "Th'apple" almost as much as "the apple." But then, I grew up in Texas. (So, yeah, it's a dialect thing, and exactly where the differences are will depend on regional variation.)